# Github Actions Functions on the console output

Tags: bash, github-actions

Say I want to validate that my code doesn't contain the `foo` string. So I'm using the Linux `grep` tool and count the output lines with `wc -l`.

Now I want to run a step only [`if`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) the results of the `grep | wc -l` eqauls to `0`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick.

```
job:
 steps:
 - run:   echo ::set-env name=GHA_COUNTER::$(grep "thing" code.h | wc -l)
   shell: bash
 - run: echo "There's a thing in my code!"
   if:  env.GHA_COUNTER == '0'
```

[`::set-env`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-environment-variable-set-env) pushes result of `grep | wc`to `env` context, which is what `if` needs to work.

If you don't want to pollute environment for any reason, [`::set-output`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-output-parameter-set-output) is another option.

```
job:
 steps:
 - run:   echo ::set-output name=things::$(grep "thing" code.h | wc -l)
   id:    counter
   shell: bash 
 - run: echo "There's a thing in my code!"
   if:  steps.counter.outputs.things == '0'
```

Comment: `::-set-env` was [deprecated for security reasons](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/) in favor of [file-based env management](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files). `::set-output` [is getting](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) the [same treatment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make sure that the command that runs grep exits unsuccessfully and then in the next step use `if: success()`.

So the grep task can use something like: `[ $(grep 'foo' action.ts | wc -l) = 0 ]`.
If the output is not zero, the command will exit with non-zero status.

In the dependent task, use `if: success()`, and this task will only run if the previous task success successful.